# Transition with Textarea's resize conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I apply `transition` to `textarea`, it's by default affect the `resize` function of it. I want to disable `transition` **only** on the `resize` action of `textarea`, but not the `textarea` it self - is this even possible to do?

```
<textarea name="" id="" class="txtarea"></textarea>

.txtarea {
  transition: 3s;
  resize: vertical;
  height: 140px;
  max-height: 350px;
  min-height: 140px;
}
```

**I'm not willing to disable `transition` entirely for the `textarea`, but only for the `resize` action**

Would be very nice to have a CSS solution, but if not, JS will be OK as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can whitelist a set of `transition` properties you need, for example `color`, and simply omit `height` from that list (the default value for `transition-property` is `all`).

Notice in the snippet below how the `color` property transitions smoothly, while resizing happens instantly.

```css
.txtarea {
  transition: color 3s;
  resize: vertical;
  height: 140px;
  max-height: 350px;
  min-height: 140px;
}

.txtarea:focus {
  color: #f00;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="" id="" class="txtarea"></textarea>
```

---

If both events require the `height` property to change, you can dynamically adjust `textarea.style.transitionProperty` when you want to trigger the smooth change:

```js
var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea')

var token

function reset (e) { e.style.transitionProperty = '' }

function setHeightSmooth (px) {
  clearTimeout(token)
  textarea.style.transitionProperty = 'all'
  textarea.style.height = px + 'px'
  token = setTimeout(reset, 3000, textarea)
}
```

```css
.txtarea {
  transition: color 3s;
  resize: vertical;
  height: 140px;
  max-height: 350px;
  min-height: 140px;
}

.txtarea:focus {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="setHeightSmooth(350)">Expand</button>
<button onclick="setHeightSmooth(140)">Collapse</button>
<br>
<textarea name="" id="" class="txtarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: I didn't notice it. Thanks! :) But what if there's same parameter involved in both scenarios... say, height, for example?

Comment: Ah, that will require a bit of JavaScript magic. Give me a few minutes to update my answer :)

Comment: Mind giving me some idea of what kind of change you are looking at in addition to resize? Is it triggered by JS code, or something else?

Comment: Only this, nothing more actually

Comment: Should have a better example now; let me know what you think.

Comment: I'll accept your answer anyway, because noticing filtering solution to the `transition` is a very important part here and very valuable (at least for me it is). But as a total solution it isn't quite right :) Try to change the `transition: color 3s;` to `transition: height 3s;` ;-)  :)

Comment: I may have misunderstood where you were heading with this solution, but I'm glad my thinking at least led you in the right direction. Good luck with the rest of your project! :)

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure I understood the question correctly but my interpretation is that you want transition for everything **except** the height. Then a simple css solution is this:

```
.txtarea {
    transition: all 3s, height 0s;
}
```

I know its a bit late but maybe this will help someone with the same question.